# AJAX code stop working suddenly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have been making a chat and at 14:09 it was working fine, it displayed messages, received them and stored them in DB. It also displayed stored messages and showed users the messages instantly. However suddenly it just stop showing all the messages. I have checked and the messages are stored in the DB when sent. I dunno what the error is as I've not changed the code to affect it. It would help a lot if you could help me with this! :)

index.php (includes AJAX jQuery & form)

```
                <div id="messageSend">
                <form action="shout.php" method="post" id="chat">
                <textarea rows="8" cols="74" id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Post messages here."></textarea> 
                <br/><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Shout!">
                </form>

                    <script>
                        $('#chat').submit(function(e) {  
                            e.preventDefault();  
                                var form = $('#chat'),  
                                url = form.attr('action'),  
                                Message = $('#Message');
                                $.post(url, {Message : Message.val()}, function(data) {  
                                $('#messageDisplay').html(data);  
                                $('#Message').empty().val('');                                    

                        });
                                                    setInterval(function() {
                              // Do something every 2 seconds

                        {
                            $.get("data.php").done(function(data) {
                            $('#messageDisplay').html(data);
                                    });
                                }
                            }, 1000);
                       });

                    </script>
```

shout.php (send message and adds to DB)

```
<?php

include 'auth.login.php';
include 'pdo.config.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
echo '<br/>';
echo '<center>You need to login to post!<br/>';
header("Refresh:2; URL=index.php");
exit();
}

if (!isset($_POST['Message']) || empty($_POST['Message'])) {
echo '<br/>';
echo '<center>Message box empty!<br/>';
exit();

}

$Username = $_SESSION['Username'];

$Message = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Message']));

$insertMessage = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO `chatbox` (User, Message) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insertMessage->bindParam(1, $Username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertMessage->bindParam(2, $Message, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertMessage->execute();


?>
```

data.php (file which has loop to retrieve messages from DB)

```
<?php

include 'pdo.config.php';

$chat = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM `chatbox`");

while($getRow = $chat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
     echo '['.date('d/m/Y g:i:s A',  strtotime($getRow['SentOn'])).'] '.$getRow['User'].': '.stripslashes($getRow['Message']).'<br/>';  
}

?>
```

Comment: What's your console say?

Comment: Where are you creating the `$_SESSION['Username']` variable? Maybe that's the problem. Sessions usually last some time and then they are dropped.

Comment: @tymeJV, On my local server it works fine, it catches data from the file data.php and displays it. Online it doesn't. In the conolse one my local server it picks up data.php online it doesn't.

Comment: @AlejandroIván, They are stored when the user logs in and dropped when they log out.

Comment: "In the conolse one my local server it picks up data.php online it doesn't" That's your problem.  Go over to the network panel and check to see what the error code and response is from your AJAX call.

Comment: @user1477388, No errors, nothing it doesn't pick that file up.

Comment: @Script47 So the file isn't on the server then.  You should be getting a 404 not found error in your network panel.  If it's online, send me a link and I'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @user1477388, Check before you post then after. http://script47.tk/Chat%20Application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page data.php is not being called.  The contents are these:

[05/09/2013 10:37:31 AM] test: test
[05/09/2013 10:37:44 AM] test: test

So, they are being inserted properly; however, when a user clicks "Shout" it does not call the `setInterval()`.

**Edit:**  Your problem is that after they login, the setInterval() isn't called.  If you refresh the page after logging in, it will work (works for me).

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chat').submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();  
        var form = $('#chat');
        url = form.attr('action'); 
        Message = $('#Message');
        $.post(url, {Message : Message.val()}, function(data) {  
            $('#messageDisplay').html(data);  
            $('#Message').empty().val('');                                    
        });

        setInterval(function() {
        // Do something every 2 seconds
            $.get("data.php").done(function(data) {
                $('#messageDisplay').html(data);
            });
        }, 1000);
    });

    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) { ?>
        setInterval(function() {
        // Do something every 2 seconds
            $.get("data.php").done(function(data) {
                $('#messageDisplay').html(data);
            });
        }, 1000);
    <?php } ?>
});
```

Comment: See my update.  It works for me after I refresh the page after logging in.

Comment: How come when I refresh it doesn't appear everything just goes?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  When you refresh, it will show messages only to those who are logged in.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: No I mean when I'm logged it and I hit F5, all the messages will disappear, any ideas?

Comment: The messages disappear because the container is empty by default.  They should reappear since you are logged in.  Don't they reappear?  They do for me.

Comment: Nah they don't for me, how long do you wait before they reappear?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36879/discussion-between-script47-and-user1477388)

Comment: Sorry I was busy earlier (and am busy now..)  I don't wait long, they appear instantly.